# A lower bound for the makespan of heterogenous fog nodes

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, distributed-systems, scheduling, modelling

[image: Pic]

Why there is a sigma in the denominator of equation (8) in the picture? suppose we have n tasks and m fog nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that $EXT(N_i) = \mathit{MinMakespan}$,
$$
\sum_{k \in N_i \mathit{Tasks}} \mathit{length}(T_k) = \mathit{MinMakespan} \times \mathit{CPUrate}(N_i).
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_k \mathit{length}(T_k) = \sum_i \sum_{k \in N_i \mathit{Tasks}} \mathit{length}(T_k) = \sum_i \mathit{MinMakespan} \times \mathit{CPUrate}(N_i) = \\ \mathit{MinMakespan} \times \sum_i \mathit{CPUrate}(N_i).
$$
It follows that
$$
\mathit{MinMakespan} = \frac{\sum_k \mathit{length}(T_k)}{\sum_i \mathit{CPUrate}(N_i)}.
$$